# How to make HTTP web service hosted on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make an HTTP web service or an HTTP action page, hosted on the iPad or any iOS device.
This service should be accessible from other devices connected on the same network using `HTTPRequest`, or using `NSURLConnection`.

Any suggestion will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a web server written in cocoa that runs inside your app and provides access to files via HTTP

---

shameless plug: see my DDSimpleHTTPd -- it is a basic webserver that runs on iOS devices

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDSimpleHTTPd

in your viewController / appDelegate you start  it like this to server any files in the specified dir:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *path = url.path;

SimpleHTTPResponder *simpleServer = [[SimpleHTTPResponder alloc] init];
simpleServer.port = 8000;
simpleServer.webRoot = path;
simpleServer.bonjourName = @"test"; //optional: allow it to be found via bonjour
simpleServer.loggingEnabled = YES; //optional: do NSLogs of the requests that come in
simpleServer.autogenerateIndex = YES; //optional: generate a directory overview

[simpleServer startListening];
```